# How to access Laravel instance when doing integration tests?

Tags: codeception

I am working on writing tests using Codeception + Selenium + PhantomJS. 
The problem that I have is that I need to mock various classes and bind different implementations in different tests (sometimes mocks of a classes with predefined results returned by their methods).

When writing Unit tests with PHPUnit that is easy:

```
    $setterMock = Mockery::mock(MyClass::class);

    $setterMock->shouldReceive('classMethod')
                ->andReturn('result');

    $this->app->instance(MyClass::class, $setterMock);
```

But when writing Integration Tests I don't know how to access the $app instance. I have tried to apply  similar code in __bootstrap.php inside the acceptance tests folder, but it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but you can't.

PhantomJS accesses the server over HTTP, so nothing can be mocked.

You could implement tests with mocks by using [Laravel5](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5) module instead of Webdriver.

Comment: I have some JS code that needs to be run. Will that module allow me to run it?